# Change an UIImage dynamically for portrait and landscape

Tags: ipad, swift, ios8.1

I'm trying to display an image in a UIImageView in portrait and landscape only for Ipad, when I added the UIImageView to the StoryBoard I set the width and height to 768x365 and the image it's showed perfect, but if the Ipad it's rotated to landscape I want to show the same image in 1024x365.

I try the following but without succeed.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    let orientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation        

    switch orientation {
    case .Portrait, .PortraitUpsideDown:
                    // 4
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1024.0, height: 365)     
        self.imageView.setNeedsDisplay()        


    case .LandscapeLeft, .LandscapeRight:
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 768.0, height: 365)     
        self.imageView.setNeedsDisplay()   

    }
```

PD : The image resolution is 1680x598

Comment: Why in code? Did you try to set the correct constraints in Interface Builder? Also, you forgot to mention what is not working ;-).

Comment: @Mundi I implement a slide show using a ScrollView and iniitally I set the width to 768 like the Ipad in portrait but the when I rotate to landscape the ScrollView maintain its width 768 not adapt to 1024 , and if I put constraints the image height it's reduced